# Expo react native Image-picker

Tags: android, react-native, io, expo

I am building an app for my school project with react native and Expo, but I have a problem when I run the app. [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGN6i.png) I am a newbie with react native and Expo and the app coding so can you guys help me ? Thanks !

Comment: Provide us some piece of code, please.

Comment: Hi @J.Doe, there is some code :

`import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Image, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
`

(photo.js imports)

Answer (score 0):

@HassJS
Hi, i think problem in your BottomTabNavigator , your import component file,
maybe you missed to export or export with different class name 
please check class name and export name and also please check import name must be different others its mixed up issue
,thanks